# What is meant when saying a function has a solution?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I have to code the solutions to these questions in Python. But before even thinking about coding, I have to understand what I have to do here.

Table 1: Observed frequency distribution of Y
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\text{Y} & 1 & 2 & 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9+\\ \hline
\text{Frequency} & 700 & 205& 50&26&10&6&1&1&1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$a)$Define $\bar\theta$ as the solution to the following function $$f(\theta)=\bar y +\frac{\theta}{(1-\theta)log(1-\theta)},$$
where $\bar y$ is the mean of the values in Table 1, that is, $f(\bar\theta)=0$.

***What is meant when saying a function has a solution?***

$b)$ Show that the condition $f(\bar\theta)=0$ is unique. (Hint: draw a graph.)

$c)$ Set up the algorithm you would use to solve for $\bar\theta$.
***Does anyone have an idea where to start?***

Comment: Probably, the solution of $f(\theta)=0$. And I don't see any differential equation here, so Picard iteration (which is a mostly theoretical method anyway) doesn't seem to apply. Maybe you meant fixed point iteration like in Newton-Raphson method...

Answer (score 1):

Re your first question: This is poor language. *Functions* do not have solutions, *equations* do. Functions have *zeros*. The definition of $\bar\theta$ should be:

> Define $\bar\theta$ as the zero of the function
>   $$
> f(\theta)=\bar y +\frac{\theta}{(1-\theta)log(1-\theta)},
> $$
>   where $\bar y$ is the mean of the values in Table 1. In other words, $\bar\theta$ is the solution to the equation $f(\bar\theta) = 0$.

Comment: Though you did not ask about it, I should point out that part b) is phrased poorly as well. It should say: Show that the condition $f(\bar\theta) = 0$ uniquely determines $\bar\theta$.

Comment: So am I understanding correctly, that question a) is in fact not a question but a statement and the first question comes up at b)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: How would you approach question c)?

Comment: I would proceed [as Normal Human suggested](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534200/what-is-meant-when-saying-a-function-has-a-solution/1534220?noredirect=1#comment3124246_1534200).